# Replace first characters of file names

Tags: r

I tried to replace the first 3 characters of 11 files with a common letter

```
x <- list.files(pattern = ".txt", )
file.rename(substring(x, 1,3), paste0("R_",1:11))
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have any files named the same as the first three letters? That is, if you have a file named `foobar.txt`, then this will try to do `file.rename("foo", "R_1")` (assuming `1:11` is meant to correspond to 11 `x` elements). I think your first argument should always be `x`, so how about `file.rename(x, paste0("R_", substr(x, 1, 3)))`.

Comment: the rename call worked, but the output was R_ + the first 3 characters

Comment: Sounds like you might want `file.rename(x, paste0("R_", 1:length(x),substring(x, 4)))`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want, ivo. Please provide at least one example of input filename and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `gsub` and a regular expression:

```
x <- list.files(pattern = ".txt")
x2 <- gsub('^.{3}', 'R_', x) # substitute first 3 characters with 'R_'
file.rename(x, x2)
```

Learning `regex` is one of the most useful skills for manipulating files in R